"Remote call timed out" error when trying to play large collection of music items with MusicKit's ApplicationMusicPlayer
I am using MusicKit ApplicationMusicPlayer to play music in my app. Everything works fine as long as I'm not playing large playlists that contain hundreds of songs. When I try to play a collection of songs that is larger than around 300 I'm always getting the error message saying:

"Prepare to play failed" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Prepare to play
failed, NSUnderlyingError=0x121d42dc0 {Error
Domain=MPMusicPlayerControllerErrorDomain Code=9 "Remote call timed
out" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Remote call timed out}}}))

It doesn't matter if songs are downloaded to the device or not.
I am aware that there is another initializer for player's queue that accepts Playlist instances but in my app users can choose to sort playlist tracks in different order than the default and that makes using that initializer not feasible for me.
I tried everything I could think of, I tried to fall back on MPMusicPlayerController and pass array of MPMusicPlayerPlayParameters to it but the result was the same.
typealias QueueEntry = ApplicationMusicPlayer.Queue.Entry

let player = ApplicationMusicPlayer.shared

let entries: [QueueEntry] = tracks
      .compactMap {
          guard let song = $0 as? Song else { return nil }
             return QueueEntry(song)
          }
Task(priority: .high) { [player] in
    do {
        player.queue = .init(entries, startingAt: nil)
        try await player.play() // prepareToPlay failed
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}


Did you try to call try await player.prepareToPlay() explicitly prior to try await player.play()? Calling it is not required, but I wonder if it can help mitigating this timeout issue

I did and the result was the same, prepareToPlay failed

Then my guess is you hit either a limit or bug, submit it to apple

Seems to be a limitation that other devs have experienced.
Rudrank Riyam has written a lot about using MusicKit, and he even posted on Twitter about your exact problem.

https://twitter.com/rudrankriyam/status/1758035733124722850
What is the use-case for a playlist of hundreds of items though?

Yeah, it seems to be the same issue, MusicKit has to be one of the worst APIs from Apple and I am sure they don't use it in the Apple Music app just judging from how quickly it performs. Such performance was easy to achieve using MediaPlayer library but MusicKit is just so slow in comparison.
"What is the use-case for a playlist of hundreds of items though?"
What do you mean? It's very common for users to have playlists containing hundreds of songs, even many of Apple Music curated playlists contain that many items.

I faced the exact problem last year when I had to deal with playlists, and as Ben mentioned, it does not work well for items over > 150.
My workaround was adding 100 songs and playing them. Then, after a delay (1 to 1.5 seconds), add 100 more songs to the queue, and repeat it until all the songs are added to the queue. That works, a bad workaround, but it works.

I’ve been doing the same thing for Spotify SDK on iOS…why these SDKs are so sh*t I cannot comprehend
